# Geo location from mongodb to elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana-4

mongo-connector is used to push the data from server which have geo location  as

```
 "location":{
    "coordinates" : {
        "lon":-77.03653,
        "lat": 38.897676
      }
  }
```

changed the properties of location as

```
"properties" :{
      "location" :{
          "type": "object",
          "properties" :{
              "coordinates": {
                  "type" : "geo_point",
                  "geohash": "true",
                  "geohash_prefix": "true"
              }
           }
      }
}
```

data is getting populated but **kibana** is not displaying any data on "tile map"

Is there anything i am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned Geo-points cannot be automatically detected with [dynamic mapping](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geopoints.html). Mapping of the data need to be created before inserting data to the database.

```
curl -XPOST :9200/databasename -d'{
    "mappings": {
      "tablename": {
        "properties": {
          "geojson_field": {"type": "geo_point"}
        }
      }
    } }'
```

please check in the [github](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/issues/220) for furthur reading.